# Getting some error in while setting up Angular using cmd

Tags: angular

I'm setting up angular using CMD.
After setting up the installation of Angular using the command "npm install -g @angular/cli" I'm trying to check Angular CLI installed with the command "ng –v", and getting the next input "'np' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to install `angular-cli` globally to use `ng`

`npm i -g @angular/cli`
to use angular-cli without global installation.

Add `ng serve --open` to the scripts section in your package.json.

`scripts:{
    "start": ng serve --open
}`

You will need to log out then log back in for the change to your PATH variable to take effect.

then run `npm start` in your project directory.

**Second way**

Just add `%AppData%\npm;` to the user variable(since %AppData% dir is depending on user) PATH to fix it.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1183

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this commond:

> ng v

Comment: ng itself is not recognized by cmd

Comment: you download node.js ?

Comment: np -v
'np' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. ( not np, it is ng )